# About Amazon AWS EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-10.10

I am new to deploy a rails3.1 app to the AWS platform(heroku only previously).

However, I want to take the advantage of EC2 + S3 free-tier micro instance.

I've heard that there's something called AMI and some other things like Capistrano etc.

Can anyone explain the whole concept of AWS cloud computing?

How can I upload files to EC2? Via the terminal?

E.g. I am using ubuntu 11.10, Can I just type "rails s" in the terminal and then Ec2 just going running in production mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon ec2 is just another service just like a dedicated server that you would get from certain hosting providers, an AMI stands for Amazon Machine Images, which is basically a pre-configured operating system, it can be any linux distro or even windows, once you decide on an AMI you will get a SSH account that you can use to connect to your server, you can use the command line to connect or any number of programs that can ssh, for instance I use zend studio on my mac and thats how I edit my files on the server but I also use the command line with the **rsync** command to backup all my files from the server to my laptop.